# Rails SQL query counts results when not asked

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This rails/sql code...

```
@new_relationships = User.select('*')
                         .from("(#{@rels_unordered.to_sql}) AS rels_unordered")
                         .joins("
                    INNER JOIN  relationships
                    ON          rels_unordered.id = relationships.character_id
                    ORDER BY    relationships.created_at DESC
                    ")
```

produces a query that begins like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT .....
```

Why is it counting the records?? I haven't asked for a count. I simply want to select all columns after the join:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT .....
```

EDIT

Ok, it looks like this is happening because the first thing I do with @new_relationships is

```
@new_relationships.any?
```

Because queries are executed lazily, the .any? is affecting the query! I would have thought rails would perform the query, get all the records into @new_relationships, and then count them. This is a surprising feature. So how do I prevent the .any? affecting the query? In other words, how do I get the query to run as intended, and then count the results afterwards?

Comment: Is this output from your rails console or server log ?

Comment: It's from the server log.

Comment: Try it in console and show me the query SQL please

Comment: Interesting. It behaves as expected in the console: SELECT * FROM (SELECT .....

Answer (score 0):

You can do the test on a `dup` of the relation, so that'll be a separate relation object that gets modified by `any?` not the original relation object.

```
@new_relationships.dup.any?
```